# Deploying an exploded WAR inside a compressed EAR == not possible?

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss-4.2.x

At the moment I am trying to deploy an exploded war directory in a compressed ear file on a jboss-4.2.3.GA server. But JBoss complains that it can't find the web-app.war file (Failed to find module file: web-app.war). However if I deploy the same ear file exploded, too, the deployment works without any problems.

So my question is: Is it generally possible to deploy an exploded war inside a compressed ear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can deploy an exploded war inside a compressed ear on jboss-5.1.0.GA.

I suggest that you can check youear.ear/META-INF/application.xml.

My appliation.xml is like this:

```
<module>
  <web>
    <web-uri>myapp-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>/myapp</context-root>
  </web>
</module>
```

and myapp-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war is an exploded war directory.

Comment: Thanks for the information that it works on JBoss 5. As I have mentioned the same EAR works if it is exploded, too. So I assume that my application.xml is just fine.